# Commit messages from Submodules to Jenkins Change Log

Tags: jenkins, git, jenkins-plugins

I have a project with 3 submodules that are updated whenever that project is built and the project is built mainly for an installer (which is not in a submodule). Not a lot of changes are made in the installer itself but the commit messages from there are coming through fine.

I'd like to also see the commit messages (changes made) from the submodules to the Jenkins log. Is this possible? If not possible there, would it be possible in the email-blast instead? In the mailer plugin, I have it configured as:

```
${CHANGES, showPaths=true, format="Commit: %r by %a \n %p \n\t Comment: %m \n", pathFormat="\n\t %p"}
```

Also, I kinda inherited Jenkins from an employee that no longer works where I work so I'm very new to this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7773010/2777965

Answer (score 1):

After consulting [this cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/git-log-format), I think that you are looking for the subject. If I apply:

```
git log --pretty="%s"
```

to one of my git repositories, the following is returned:

```
learning pointers in golang
receiver struct in golang
embedded structs in golang
multiple spanish words
```

In conclusion, I think you should include `%s` to get the git messages or basically the `commit subjects`.